# Inconsistent realm data between threads

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a case where I need to populate realm with a series of objects upon user request. To populate realm I make a network call then write the objects to realm. When the write is complete, the background thread invokes a callback that switches to the main thread to process the results. I would much prefer to use realm notifications but this is a very specific use case and notifications are not an option.

I can't share my full project but I was able to reproduce this issue with a sample project. Here is my data model.

```
class Owner: Object {
    @objc dynamic var uuid: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    convenience init(uuid: String, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.name = name
    }

    func fetchDogs() -> Results<Dog>? {
        return realm?.objects(Dog.self).filter("ownerID == %@", uuid)
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uuid"
    }
}

class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var uuid: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var ownerID: String = ""

    func fetchOwner() -> Owner? {
        return realm?.object(ofType: Owner.self, forPrimaryKey: ownerID)
    }

    convenience init(uuid: String, name: String, ownerID: String) {
        self.init()
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.name = name
        self.ownerID = ownerID
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uuid"
    }
}
```

I realize that a `List` would be appropriate for the `Owner` -> `Dog` relationship but that's not an option in this project.

In the sample project there are two buttons that we care about. One to add some `Dog` objects to realm and associate them with the `Owner` UUID. The other button deletes all of the `Dog` objects that belong to the owner.

The basic flow is like this:

- Delete all of the owner's dogs
- Create a new set of dogs on a background thread and add them to realm.
- Invoke a callback
- Switch back to the main thread
- Print all of the owner's dogs

Nine times out of ten the dogs are printed out successfully. However, sometimes realm indicates that there are no dogs associated with the current owner. What could be the reason for this? My view controller logic is below.

EDIT: The last thing I should mention is that this issue is only only reproducible on a physical device. I can't reproduce it on the simulator. That makes me wonder if this is a realm bug.

```
// MARK: - Props and view controller life cycle

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var owner: Owner?
    let ownerUUID = UUID().uuidString

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        owner = makeOwner()
    }
}

// MARK: - Action methods

extension ViewController {

    @IBAction func onDeletePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Deleting...")
        deleteDogs()
    }

    @IBAction func onRefreshPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Creating...")
        createDogs {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.printDogs()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onPrintPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        printDogs()
    }
}

// MARK: - Helper methods

extension ViewController {

    private func makeOwner() -> Owner? {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let owner = Owner(uuid: ownerUUID, name: "Bob")
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(owner)
        }
        return owner
    }

    private func deleteDogs() {
        guard let dogs = owner?.fetchDogs() else { return }
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(dogs)
        }
    }

    private func createDogs(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue(label: "create.dogs.background").async {
            autoreleasepool {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let dogs = [
                    Dog(uuid: UUID().uuidString, name: "Fido", ownerID: self.ownerUUID),
                    Dog(uuid: UUID().uuidString, name: "Billy", ownerID: self.ownerUUID),
                    Dog(uuid: UUID().uuidString, name: "Sally", ownerID: self.ownerUUID),
                ]
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(dogs)
                }
            }
            completion()
        }
    }

    private func printDogs() {
        guard let dogs = owner?.fetchDogs() else { return }
        print("Dogs: \(dogs)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things. When you say *background thread* are you meaning one created with .qos of background? as in `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`? The second thing is that the way this code is structured, there is no *relationship* between owners and dogs at all. Those are totally separate, independent objects with no graph between them. Because if that, the question boils down to; I have two sets of objects. If I delete one set of objects, then create another set on a 'background thread' then switch back to the main thread and try to print them and they are not there.

Comment: Also where does the `realm` come from in owner.fetchDogs? You may want to look into `Realm.refresh()` and with a quick look, those created dogs appear to be on a totally different thread than the rest of the data. Also this is a good read [Using a Realm across threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) which may add some clarity

Comment: @Jay When I say background thread I simply mean a thread other than the main thread. And, you are correct, there are no actual relationships between the owner and the dog. No List, no LinkingObjects. Instead, the Dog object has a property called ownerID to associate the two.

Comment: @Jay The `realm` property in owner.fetchDogs is inherited by the `Object` class. You are correct, the Dog objects are intentionally created on a background thread. In my actual project we make a network request, store that data in realm on a separate thread, then invoke the callback. The created dogs and the rest of the data are supposed to be on different threads.

Comment: @Jay You were right. `Realm.refresh()` was one solution. If you want to post a solution I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the the dogs are created on a separate thread; a 'background thread' and because of that it won't have a run loop - so the two threads are looking at different states of the data.

When creating objects on a thread with no runloop, Realm.refresh() must be called manually in order to advance the transaction to the most recent state.

Check out the documentation on [Seeing changes from other threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads)

Comment: I discovered another solution. If I hadn't maintained a reference to the Owner, and simply fetched the owner from realm whenever I needed it, a refresh would not have been necessary.

Comment: @Rob very true as that object would exist on the same thread. However, if your using the objects in the UI, a tableView for example, that adds some complexity.